# Ubuntu dual boot on external HDD

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 10 installed on my External HDD, cause my computer HDD is broken. Anyway, I was saying, is it possible to dualboot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on my external hdd? If yes then how??

Comment: The same way you would normally do it. Am I wrong?

Comment: I really don't know. Thats what I'am asking for

Comment: It is the same way. You should be able to select the correct HDD during install. Use the something else option. Your HDD should be listed as something like `/dev/sdc` Tell me how you go... Does your PC support UEFI btw? Is your windows installed as UEFI? If so make sure you install Ubuntu as UEFI too.

Comment: No my pc support UEFI but the boot is setted to Legacy

Comment: Why? UEFI is much better than Legacy! You can easily and safely change the boot mode through Windows. There is an inbuilt utility. Which version is your windows?

Comment: I cant use UEFI ._. my pc already have legacy. is something will happen if i switched to UEFI?

Comment: I have windows 10 by  the way.

Comment: You can change your Windows and the whole disk to UEFI and GPT safely through Windows. I asked which version of windows 10? type winver in search bar. You should get something like version 1909, 2004, etc

Comment: Reas this. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10 If you don't have windows installation media, the allowfullos command should work. I converted my own Windows using it. Do this before you install Ubuntu

Comment: I have Win10 2004

Comment: Then that should work fine...

Comment: How did it go??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install ubuntu alongside Windows in your external hdd.
It's the same way you install in your internal hdd.
Check this out :
[Install Ubuntu and Windows in Dual boot](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)